# Android Studio Arctic Fox unable to run JUnit configuration with mockk

Tags: android, android-studio, junit5, mockk

I just upgrade my Android Studio to the latest one. And currently I guess some of my test classes producing flaky test result and I want to run repeat mode in Android Studio as I did in Android Studio 4.2. But I found that I got the following exception

Even I tried with a simple test class i still get this error. I run with Gradle Test runner and it works as expected but i cannot use it to run the test class repeatly to see if there is any flaky result in my test class

Appreciate any comment or advice :)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/mockk/proxy/MockKAgentFactory

    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<init>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:198)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<clinit>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:186)
    at com.example.testCorrect(Student.kt:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.mockk.proxy.MockKAgentFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 68 more
```

```
import io.mockk.mockk
import junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class StudentTest {
    @Test
    fun testCorrect() {
        val mockStudent = mockk<Student>()
        assertEquals(1,1)
    }
}

class Student(
    val name:String
)
```

[image]

**Update:**

I just create a Hello World project and use the simple configuration as mention above. In "Gradle Test Runner" configuration, it works. But in "JUnit" configuration, same error is occurred

Comment: Have you tried invalidating caches and doing a project clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes, i have tried it many times but no luck

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`android-gradle-plugin` removes runtime dependencies during IDE project import. Earlier days Android Studio [had](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/0cd6b4fb52818caf2c102e1d22f189314063e310) dedicated IDE feature that extended JUnit run configuration classpath to include runtime dependencies. Now you have to recover classpath yourself (or better avoid JUnit run configuration in Android projects). Android Studio moves to a direction that everything should be delegated to Gradle (e.g. see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#bumblebee-unified-test-runner).

Since you are using JUnit5, `@RepeatedTest(10_000_000)` or the like might be an easier option.

TL; DR;

`MockKAgentFactory` is available from `io.mockk:mockk-agent-api`. I added the following to make your example work:

```
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.12.0"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-agent-jvm:1.12.0"
    testImplementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: '1.5.30'
```

The trick is in Android Gradle Plugin. It builds (at least) 2 classpathes: compile and runtime. IDE Android Plugin (in Android Studio) imports only libraries from Compile classpath (runtime entries are removed). When running tests with the Gradle runner, IDE delegates execution to gradle, and Gradle invokes tests with the Runtime classpath. When running tests with JUnit in Android Studio, JUnit uses runtime classpath of an IDE module as it's seen by the IDE (which already has no runtime libs because they were removed during import). Check External Libraries section to see what exactly is added to the IDE project.
[image]

If the project was a regular java project, IDE would add `mockk-agent-jvm` and its transitive dependency `mockk-agent-api`. Note that `mockk-agent-jvm` is a `RUNTIME` dependency of `io.mockk:mockk` (see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/mockk/mockk/1.12.0/mockk-1.12.0.pom). `android-gradle-plugin` removes runtime dependencies during import.  When running from IDE with gradle run configuration, you can set a breakpoint in the beginning of any test method and check the stacktrace. Full test runtime classpath is available one frame before JUnitRunner is invoked by gradle. E.g.:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is the only solution working for me. However, after i added this i encounter other unexpected issues with other third party libraries. I think it might be better to have Android 4.2 when I need to run some test case repeatly.

Comment: This is a great answer, and deserves more than the single upvote I can give to it!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.mockk.proxy.MockKAgentFactory
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> ```

This is the error part.
It is saying that class not found exception which means that there is a class mentioned somewhere but if not found or not present.
Or if you are using an implementation, delete the implementation and put them again.
This works for me.
Even I faced same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no luck on it :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding this to your app level build.gradle:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different problem/solutions come to my mind.

1. You probably forgot to add `mockk` in your Gradle configuration like below:

```
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:{version}"
```

And probably in previous Android Studio, it was being served from Gradle caches.

---

2. I don't know why, but Arctic Fox switches to my custom installed JDK (1.8) every time I open a project for the first time and I face some CNF exceptions in my builds. After changing it to the embedded JDK, everything works as it should. You can go to **Preferences -> Build, Execution -> Build Tools -> Gradle** and change **Gradle SDK** to the Embedded JDK. As I can see in your screenshot, you're also running the tests using a custom installed JDK 11. However, `mockk` is not inside JDK so I guess my first suggestion might suits better.

[image: Gradle JDK]

Comment: For the first suggestion, yes, i have already added it and it works with "Gradle Test Runner" but not with "JUnit" configuration. I tried the second suggestion but not work.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the test runner annotation

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
```

also you need to check your build.gradle(app) file for the following

```
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.2.0"
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.8.0'
```

Comment: No, i am not using mockito and this solution also not work for me if i change to mockk

Comment: I found this github issue related to the error u r getting check it out https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/605